# Switching the system does not work

Tags: system, windbg

I had the following situation: I'm in a live user mode debugging session and I wanted to show the `win32k!_W32Process` structure. Unfortunately, win32k is a kernel mode SYS file, so the symbols are not available in the user mode session.

I know that I can always load a DLL, EXE or SYS as a dump file and then inspect the symbols. Usually I would do that via File/Open Crash Dump.

This time, I wanted to show the participants of a debugging workshop that it's possible to debug multiple systems at the same time, so I opened the Win32K.sys via WinDbg's command prompt:

```
0:003> |
.  0    id: 10fc    attach  name: [...]\NetHeaps.exe

0:003> .opendump C:\Windows\winsxs\[...]\win32k.sys
Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\winsxs\[...]\win32k.sys]
Opened 'C:\Windows\winsxs\[...]\win32k.sys'

||0:0:003>
```

As we can now see, we have 2 systems and I'm currently on the live debugging system:

```
||0:0:003> ||
.  0 Live user mode: <Local>
   1 Image file: C:\Windows\winsxs\[...]\win32k.sys
```

I thought I could switch to the other system now, but that does not work:

```
||0:0:003> ||1s
              ^ Illegal debuggee error in '||1s'
```

I would not have worried too much, but it can't find the symbols of `win32k` in this case:

```
||0:0:003> .reload
Reloading current modules
...........................
||0:0:003> dt win32k!_W32Process
Symbol win32k!_W32Process not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in the `||` command, it's in the `.opendump` command.

The help says:

> After you use the .opendump command, you must use the g (Go) command to finish loading the dump file.

Be aware that this will also run your live process. Therefore, freeze the threads first (`~*f`) and unfreeze later (`~*u`).

After that you can switch the system and display the type:

```
||1:1:004> ||
   0 Live user mode: <Local>
.  1 Image file: C:\Windows\winsxs\[...]\win32k.sys

||1:1:004> dt _W32Process
win32k!_W32PROCESS
   +0x000 Process          : Ptr64 _EPROCESS
   +0x008 RefCount         : Uint4B
   +0x00c W32PF_Flags      : Uint4B
[...]
```

Comment: Wow, that's awful.